# How can I highlight non-adjacent table cells on mouseover?

Tags: onmouseover

I am trying to set up a mouseover highlight effect for a round-robin style tournament so that when a person puts the mouse over player A's results against player B, that cell as well as the cell showing player B's results against player A are both highlighted. To illustrate the point, here is the page I would like to highlight: http://yppc.zzl.org/groups.html . I have yet to find a mouseover script that can highlight non-adjacent cells at the same time. I have seen this effect on another website, but unfortunately the league is not in session and the scores have been taken down.

Thanks for any assistance you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function hl(cell, enable)
            {
                var rIndex = cell.cellIndex;
                var cIndex = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
                var cell2 = cell.parentNode.parentNode.rows[rIndex].cells[cIndex];

                if (enable) {
                    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
                    cell2.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
                } else {
                    cell.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
                    cell2.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A</td>
                <td></td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">A:B</td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">A:C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">B:A</td>
                <td></td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">B:C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>C</td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">C:A</td>
                <td onmouseover="hl(this, true)" onmouseout="hl(this, false)">C:B</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <table>
    </body>
</html>
```